# How to clone elasticsearch index to another index using python requests library?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, python-requests

I am trying to do as in title with the following code:

```
resp = requests.post("http://es_7:9200/my-index/_clone/new-my-index")
```

And I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://es_7:9200/my-index/_clone/new-my-index
```

Seems like it is not existing query, but as per docs it should work fine.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clone-index.html

What may be the issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This route was added in the release [7.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/release-notes-7.4.0.html)

Could it be you are using a prior release ?

> I am using version 7.0.1 how to clone the index within this version?

#### To perform a clone like operation:

In the case you wish to perform a `_clone` artificially.

Say you have `index1` as the original index and `index2` being the clone,

I believe you have to :

- Get the [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) and [settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html) of `index1`
- [Create](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) `index2` with the said setting/mapping
- [_reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) the data from `index1` to `index2`

Comment: I am using version 7.0.1 how to clone the index within this version?

Comment: you need to upgrade, 7.0 is very well past EOL. the other approach you can take here is to reindex

Comment: @MarkWalkom I have to use this version unfortunately. Wouldn't using reindex move my whole index to the new one while the source index would be empty?

Comment: @PawelBuchajczuk I edited my response, does it helps ?